# php vs htaccess redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I'm looking for a detailed explanation of PHP redirect vs htaccess redirect. Question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094932/4988978) but my scenario is little different than that.

I have an old site lets say www.mydomain.com/oldsite/
And my new site is www.mydomain.com/newsite/

This is a wordpress installation on /oldsite and there are so many posts and writing all of them in htacccess is very lengthy process so if I just put a php code in header.php of theme before any html output which will redirect page to new address is it a good practice or should I switch to htaccess.
Code I'm using is

```
if (is_singular('post')){

 $link = get_the_permalink();
 $new_link = str_replace("oldsite","newsite",$link);

 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
 header("Location:".$new_link); 
 exit();

}
```

URL structure on /newsite is bit different than /oldsite and I'm handling all posts and archives redirection with php after appending the URL structure changes in string before php redirection.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real functional difference. Apache with a `.htaccess` and PHP will both issue a 301 header redirect. Neither is better (or even a "best practice") redirect over the other. At the end of the day, a header is a header.