# How to Redirect user to oldest published post in case of duplicate post using htacess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to redirect the user on my oldest post in case of the Duplicate post using htaccess redirection. For example:

- https://example.com/my-first-post/
- https://example.com/my-first-post-2/

In the above 2 URL's first one is the original post and the second one is its duplicate. I would like an htaccess redirection rule to send all the users who land on URL containing **-2/** to its original post.

Comment: At top of your old file put `header("Location:https://example.com/my-first-post-2/");` No need htaccess :-)

Comment: I have a wordpress website and the posts are duplicate like every post gets published 2 time one with normal url and other url with -2/ at the end... now -2/ is distinguishing element... i want all the posts with -2/ at the end of url to redirect to url with out -2/ in it/

Answer (score 0):

**Another Way:** The only difference could be delay, since the .htaccess is processed before the php file, but [I think the delay insignificantly small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094932/htaccess-redirect-vs-php-redirect).

At top of your old file put

```
header("Location:https://example.com/my-first-post-2/"); exit;
```

No need htaccess if there is no worry for trafic